# Shuffle sorted subarrays

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, collections, shuffle

Let's say I have an object with one significant criteria, and perhaps some other data.

```
class MyObject {
    int criteria;
    String otherData;
}
```

I want to "shuffle-sort" a list such that given the data x,y such that x is the criteria and y is the otherData, all the similar x's are grouped (and sorted) but within the subgroup, it is shuffled

My goal given sequential runs, might give the following results

```
/ 1s first\|/ 2s next \|/ then 3s \
-----------------------------------
1,a 1,b 1,c 2,d 2,e 2,f 3,g 3,h 3,i // other data is in
1,a 1,c 1,b 2,e 2,d 2,f 3,i 3,h 3,g // a random order
1,c 1,a 1,b 2,d 2,f 2,e 3,h 3,i 3,g // within the subgroup
1,b 1,c 1,c 2,e 2,d 2,f 3,g 3,h 3,i
```

My current plan is to create a Comparable that only compares the first criteria. Then my "shuffle-sort" could simply

```
list.shuffle(); // get a random ordering
list.sort(); // now group by criteria, leaving the others in a still random state
```

My question is, is this the most efficient way to do this? Is it going to actually achieve my objective? Is there some pattern that might emerge from this? If so, what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will work and is asymptotically optimal. It's easiest to analyze if you make sure to use a stable sort, but I think the grouping phase won't introduce bias regardless.

If you want to write code that more obviously expresses your intent, you could insert values into a `TreeMap<Integer, List<MyObject>>`, grouping all values of a given integer into the same list. Then iterate over the contents of the map in key-order (lowest to highest), shuffling each sublist and then dumping its contents into a final output list. In my eyes that approach is more "obviously correct" but I believe yours works just as well.

Comment: The comparator does not know about the unsorted fields. Thus I am quite sure there is no way for an unstable sort to introduce bias here.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. All I meant was that if you wanted to make a formal argument, you'd need to say that (a) the sort has permute without respect to the other fields, and (b) that uniformly permutating the order of an unbiased random shuffle is also an unbiased random shuffle. These two facts seem obvious, but they do make the argument a little more subtle.

Answer (score 1):

The only optimization I see on your approach would be to use some sort of shuffling iterator instead of actualy shuffling the data. But this won't change the complexity of your algorithm, because shuffling cost is at worst linear and sorting is at best n log(n)

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you are trying to do, *before* you think about the implementation, and try to find a good fit from the existing JDK classes.

I would be using a [`Map<Integer, List<MyObject>>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) which would solve the grouping issue straight away, then I could [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) the lists, and if I *really* wanted a single list, I could dump the Lists in the map values into one list:

```
Map<Integer, List<MyObject>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<MyObject>>();
...
List oneList = new ArrayList<MyObject>(map.values());
for (List<?> list : map.values())
    oneList.addAll(list);
```

Comment: I had thought about this, but this is in the most time critical loop in the application. It must re-order the priorities every iteration, and doing this I would have to recreate the entire map/list structure each time. I also see that I would have to sort the `oneList` to make sure they all came in the proper order, seeing as how `values()` has no order assigned to it.

Comment: I should also note that the length of the list cannot be longer than 10, which further increases the magnitude of this overhead.

Comment: You can use an ordered map to maintain order by the `int criteria`. Also, I am suggesting you keep the map fulltime and only render into a list when you absolutely need to - or change your app to work with a map. And btw, it should be `criterion`, not `criteria`: `criteria` is the *plural* of `criterion`, and you only have one `int`, unless it's a bitmask :)

Comment: The int represents the set of all criteria, which happens to contain one element. :-) Anywho, it has to be rendered into a list with every iteration, unfortunately. It needs to be available for decision algorithms to properly make their decision. If I don't have a list for them to make their decision, they may get a different result even in the same iteration, which they shouldn't.